# type is erased from implicit class

Tags: scala, implicit, type-erasure, classtag

I'm having a implicit class to add a certain function for a case class, for example:

```
case class TestClass(name:String)

implicit class ChangeProduct[S <: Seq[T], T <: Product](seq: Option[Seq[T]]) {
    def convert(expr: T => T): Option[Seq[T]] = seq.map(_.map(expr))
}

val c = Option(List(TestClass("a"), TestClass("b")))
val r = c.convert(p => p.copy(name = p.name.toUpperCase()))
println(r)
```

I'm happy to see the output is

```
Some(List(TestClass(A), TestClass(B)))
```

But now I try to make the implicit class more generic by change its parameter to `seq:Option[S]`:

```
implicit class ChangeProduct[S <: Seq[T], T <: Product](seq: Option[S]) {
    def convert(expr: T => T): Option[S] = seq.map(_.map(expr))
}

val c = Option(List(TestClass("a"), TestClass("b")))
val r = c.convert(p => p.copy(name = p.name.toUpperCase()))
println(r)
```

Unfortunately I got error message:

```
Error:(37, 51) type mismatch;
   found   : Seq[T]
   required: S
        def convert(expr: T => T): Option[S] = seq.map(_.map(expr))
```

And for expression `p.copy(name = p.name.toUpperCase())`, it said

```
Type mismatch.
    Required: Nothing => Nothing
    Found : Nothing => Any
```

I think it might be type erasure problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I figured it out. If I do want limit the `S` be sub type of `Seq`, I should give it an explicit parameter instead of underscore. And also because I have `T <: Product`, the `U` must be covariant:

```
implicit class ChangeProduct[S[+U] <: Seq[U], T <: Product](seq: Option[S[T]]) {
    def convert(expr: T => T): Option[Seq[T]] = seq.map(_.map(expr))
}

val c = Option(List(TestClass("a"), TestClass("b")))
val r = c.convert(p => p.copy(name = p.name.toUpperCase()))
println(r)
```

Thanks @Mario Galic and @Alexey Romanov

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not type erasure but we need to use type constructor `S[_]` instead of just `S`. Consider [`Functor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58293767/5205022) constraint

```
S[_]: Functor
```

like so

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

case class TestClass(name:String)

implicit class ChangeProduct[S[_]: Functor, T](s: Option[S[T]]) {
  def convert(expr: T => T): Option[S[T]] = s.map(_.map(expr))
}

val c = Option(List(TestClass("a"), TestClass("b")))
c.convert(p => p.copy(name = p.name.toUpperCase()))
```

which outputs

```
res0: Option[List[TestClass]] = Some(List(TestClass(A), TestClass(B)))
```

Comment: This looks work somehow, why I have to use `Functor` instead of `Seq[T]`? what if I hope S to be subtype of a sequence? Functor doesn't do it, is it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. The reason for the first error message is that `map` on `S` doesn't have to return `S`. It usually does, but it isn't guaranteed, and certainly not encoded in the types.
2. The reason for `Nothing` is that unfortunately Scala's type inference can't handle inferring `T` and `S` together in this situation.

You can fix both problems (in 2.13) by using [`IterableOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOps.html) as the bound instead:

```
implicit class ChangeProduct[S[A] <: IterableOps[A, S, S[A]], T <: Product](seq: Option[S[T]]) {
    def convert(expr: T => T): Option[S[T]] = seq.map(_.map(expr))
}
```

(the `Product` bound doesn't seem to be useful here).